# how do i use name in frontend and send id on selected

Tags: angular, development-environment, bootstrap-typeahead

```
<input *ngIf="showAutoComplete"
       [(ngModel)]="selected"
       [typeahead]="uniqueCreatedBys"
       [typeaheadOptionField]="'name'"
       class="form-control"
       (ngModelChange)=
       "ObjectType('',userId =  selected.id )">
```

i am using typehead of ngx bootstarp and need to access the name in frontend part but send id in the ObjectType function,  my uniqueCreatedBys contains the list of both name and id

//and this is my function

```
ObjectType(q?: string, userId? : number, offset?: number, limit?: number) {
    // console.log(this.objectTypes)
    // const userId = this.selected ? this.objectTypes.find(obj => obj.createdBy === this.selected)?.createdById : undefined;
    this.objectTypeService.fetchObjectTypes(q, userId , offset, limit).subscribe((response: any) => {
      this.objectTypeService.resetObjectTypes();
      this.objectTypeService.setObjectTypes(response);

      this.objectTypes = this.objectTypeService.getObjectTypes();
      this.totalCount = this.objectTypeService.getTotalDocsCount();

      this.uniqueCreatedBys = this.getUniqueCreatedBys(this.objectTypes);
      console.log(this.uniqueCreatedBys)
    });
  }
```

Comment: can you add your `ObjectType` function here what params its expecting

Comment: i have added the function also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of `ngModelChange` You can use [onSelect](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/components/typeahead?tab=overview#on-select) something like

```
<input *ngIf="showAutoComplete"
       [(ngModel)]="selected"
       [typeahead]="uniqueCreatedBys"
       [typeaheadOptionField]="'name'"
       class="form-control"
       (typeaheadOnSelect)=
       "ObjectType('',$event.item?.id )">
```

Working [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-bootstrap-typeahead-highlight-bug-7rd1gk?file=app/app.component.ts)

Comment: this did not gave the desired result